# Show that a group with $p^k$ elements where $p$ is prime has a subgroup of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Proof-

Pick an element $a \in G, \, a\not= e$

Now order $(a) = p^t$ for some $1 \leq t \leq k$ $\,$(by Lagrange)

If I could show that $t \not= k$ so $G$ is not cyclic, I could use an inductive argument to show that there's an element of order $p$

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_theorem_(group_theory)), the wiki article on Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @vadim123 I saw that, but we haven't learnt that yet. I was wondering if there was a direct proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're **very** close.

Pick a non-identity $g \in G$ and consider the subgroup $H = \langle g \rangle$.  By Lagrange's theorem, $|H| = p^n$ for some $n$.

If $n \neq 1$, don't despair!  $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$.  As such, we can find subgroup of $H$ of order $m$ for every divisor $m$ of $|H|$.  In particular...

---

[This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups) might be of interest for future readers.

Comment: I can't see why $H$ should be cyclic. That's the only gap I'm missing

Comment: @Jack, that's the easy part: it's generated by powers of $g$.  That is, $H = \{g, g^2, g^3, ... \}$.

Comment: Oh right! Completely missed that

Comment: Rather than induction, you can just observe that (1) $n \ne 0$, since $g$ is not the identity, and (2) $g^{p^{n-1}}$ is an element of order $p$. That's what I was hinting at in my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

What's the order of $a^{p^{t-1}}$? Note that $t \ne 1$, because $a \ne e$.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an induction argument in disguise:

Suppose, by way of contradiction, the theorem is NOT true. Then there is a minimal counter-example: a group $G$ of mininal order $p^k$ (where $k \geq 1$) with no element of order $p$. In fact, we see $k > 1$, since any group of order $p$ has an element of order $p$ (any generator).

Similarly, we see $G$ cannot be cyclic, for if $G = \langle x\rangle$, then $x^{p^{k-1}}$ has order $p$.

Therefore, there is some $g\neq e \in G$ such that $\{e\} \neq H = \langle g\rangle \neq G$.

Now $|H| = p^m$, where $1 \leq m < k$. Since $G$ has no elements of order $p$, neither does $H$, contradicting the minimality of the order of $G$.

Hence there is no minimal counter-example, that is: the theorem is true.

Answer (score 0):

As you did in iduction, if $G$ is not cylic you are done. If it is cyclic $|a|=p^k$. But then use induction on $H=<a^p>$ then $H$ is proper in $G$.